# Update data term of Gibbs energy in GrabCut

Tags: c++, opencv, image-processing, computer-vision, image-segmentation

I was going through the [GrabCut](https://cvg.ethz.ch/teaching/cvl/2012/grabcut-siggraph04.pdf) algorithm and I wanted to update the data term of the Gibbs energy to the following:

[image: eq]

where, [image: fr] and [image: bg]. p^f and p^b are the Gaussian Mixture Model (GMM) with 4 and 8 components respectively. I was going through the code of [GrabCut](https://github.com/opencv/opencv/blob/master/modules/imgproc/src/grabcut.cpp), where I can see that smoothness is calculated in *calcNWeights()* function. But what I couldn't find is the calculation of data term. How is the data term is calculated in the code and how to update it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Calculating the data term in Graph Cuts is to calculate the *t*-links.  That is shown in the source code on line 465 of the `grabcut.cpp` source - specifically within the `constructGCGraph` function: https://github.com/opencv/opencv/blob/master/modules/imgproc/src/grabcut.cpp#L465.  Take note that the declaration of the function is `static void`, meaning that it's private and not visible outside of the `cv` workspace.  This means you are not able to call it within your source code unless you hack into the source itself.

In other words:

```
// set t-weights
double fromSource, toSink;
if( mask.at<uchar>(p) == GC_PR_BGD || mask.at<uchar>(p) == GC_PR_FGD )
{
    fromSource = -log( bgdGMM(color) );
    toSink = -log( fgdGMM(color) );
}
else if( mask.at<uchar>(p) == GC_BGD )
{
    fromSource = 0;
    toSink = lambda;
}
else // GC_FGD
{
    fromSource = lambda;
    toSink = 0;
}
graph.addTermWeights( vtxIdx, fromSource, toSink );
```

The terminology of "source" and "sink" come from the Graph Cuts algorithm where "source" means a foreground pixel and "sink" means a background pixel.  Also note that there are four types of labels.  These are defined in an `enum` called `cv::GrabCutClasses` (you can find them here: https://docs.opencv.org/3.0.0/d7/d1b/group__imgproc__misc.html#gad43d3e4208d3cf025d8304156b02ba38).

Specifically:

- `GC_BGD`: an obvious background pixel
- `GC_FGD`: an obvious foreground (object) pixel
- `GC_PR_BGD`: a possible background pixel
- `GC_PR_FGD`: a possible foreground pixel

`GC_BGD` and `GC_FGD` are pixels that represent the foreground and background strokes used to delineate the image.  These are what you specify.  For `GC_PR_BGD` and `GC_PR_FGD`, we thus rely on building the GMMs for the foreground and background and compute the negative log probabilities.  The essence behind this is that if the colour definitely belongs to the foreground, we assign a low cost tying it to the sink node so that it is more attractive to cut this link to leave the source node intact, thus classifying it as a foreground pixel.  You can similarly do this for the source node and the background.  For those pixels where we definitely know if they're foreground or background, we apply a high cost `lambda` to the link representative of the desired label so the opposite link gets cut, thus retaining the desired label for the pixel.  For example, if we know that a pixel is background, we ensure that the *t*-link cost to the source node is zero so that we can cut this link without any ramifications ensuring that the pixel is assigned to the background.

To "update" the data terms, that is done by specifying more foreground and background strokes in the image to give a better description of the object you are trying to segment.  There is no other way to do this without hacking into the source yourself.

As a final note, I'd recommend reading this summary on how the Graph Cuts algorithm works: [Image segmentation with maxflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23997801/image-segmentation-with-maxflow/24073174#24073174).  It gives more perspective on what the source code for GrabCut is doing.  After all, GrabCut is simply a higher-level abstraction of Graph Cuts.

Comment: If we look at the original paper https://cvg.ethz.ch/teaching/cvl/2012/grabcut-siggraph04.pdf the equation of the data term in equation 9 is completely different from the one used above, i.e., -log( bgdGMM(color) ) and -log( fgdGMM(color) ). They are just calculating the -log of the GMM.

Comment: so what exactly are the developer implementing in GrabCut? What is the Gibbs Energy equation they are optimizing ?

Comment: One more question. In my problem case, I need to calculate the data term by adding the -log(p_f) and -log(p_b). But in the source code of GrabCut they are calculating -log(p_f) and -log(p_b) differently and then passing it to graph.addTermWeights() function. What should I do here ?

Comment: I'm a bit confused. Your question states how the data cost is calculated which is exactly what the source code is doing. What is it that you believe is wrong?

Comment: Actually you have answered my question, but I was just asking my doubts in the comments.

Comment: Oh I see. I understand. Let me know if you need anything else!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/189376/discussion-between-ansh-kumar-and-rayryeng).